# Observable containers

Tags: c++, c++11

I often face situations where I need to create a selection from a data source, manipulate the selection and feed the changes back to the original data source. Something like

```
#include <vector>

void manipulate(std::vector<int> &vector) {
    // Manipulate vector...
}

int main() {
    // Data source
    std::vector<int> dataSource{1, 2, 3, 4};

    // Select every second entry
    std::vector<int> selection{v[0], v[2]};

    // Manipulate selection
    manipulate(selection);

    // Feed data back to the data source
    dataSource[0] = selection[0];
    dataSource[2] = selection[1];

    return 0;
}
```

In order to automate the process of feeding the data back to the data source, I could change the selection to a vector of pointers or references (using `std::reference_wrapper`) and pass that to the function which manipulates its argument. Alternatively, I could create a class `ObservableVector` which holds the data source as a member and propagates all changes made to it to the data source. However, in both cases, I would need to change the signature of `manipulate` to accept a vector of pointers or an `ObservableVector`. Is there any chance I can keep the original `manipulate` function (without the need to create a wrapper function) and still automate the process of feeding the data back to the original source?

Comment: Your selection vector doesn't store original positions of selected elements. You need to store them elsewhere. Perhaps in a parallel vector of indices (or, for more generality, iterators). You can create a `Selection` class that would store selected elements and their positions in separate containers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may wrap your logic into a function, something like:

```
template <typename T, typename F>
void manipulate_selection(std::vector<T>& v,
                          F f,
                          const std::vector<std::size_t>& indexes)
{
    std::vector<T> selection;

    // Select every second entry
    selection.reserve(indexes.size());
    for (auto index : indexes) {
        selection.pusk_back(v[index]);
    }

    // Manipulate selection
    f(selection);

    // Feed data back to the data source
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i != indexes.size(); ++i) {
        v[indexes[i]] = selection[i];
    }
}
```

And then use it like:

```
manipulate_selection(dataSource, manipulate, {0, 2});
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at a `range` library, e.g. [Boost.Range](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/range/doc/html/index.html). A range can be created from a container to contain a subset of the container, e.g. every nth element, or a range with all elements that match a predicate object. With that, it is easy to compose complex manipulations. The following is some sample code which iterates over every second element of a container, filters it and then computes something

```
using namespace boost::adaptors;
using namespace boost;

// assume we have a predicate int -> bool
bool pred(int x);

// some function which transforms each element
int computation(int);

std::vector<int> elements = // ...

auto everySecondElement = elements | strided(2);
auto filtered = everySecondElement | filtered(pred);

transform( filtered, filtered.begin(), computation);
```

That is more a function-programming style which makes composition of range processing really easy and expressive. It probably requires changes to your manipulation functions, but I think using a range library greatly improves C++ code.